# Can't Access Protected Method of Instantiated Class

Tags: java, jsp, protected, aem

I am trying to access this protected class: `protected boolean canDraw()`, and get its value placed into a variable.  Two ways I'm trying to access it are not working:

```
    <%@ page import="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image" %>
    <%@include file="/apps/tju/global.jsp"%>
    <% //..... 
       Image thisImage = new Image(resource); %>
```

`boolean foo = thisImage.canDraw();` throws **The method canDraw() from the type Image is not visible**

and

`boolean foo = super.canDraw();` throws **The method canDraw() is undefined for the type HttpJspBase**

Full javadoc of the class being used can be found here: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Image.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is protected.  Therefore, you cannot access it from outside of the package and the classes which inherit from the class.

You are trying to access a protected method from a JSP page.  The JSP page is not a sub-class of Image and therefore cannot access the method.

If there is not a better way to do what you're trying to do, subclass Image and make a public accessor for the attribute you're trying to access.

Comment: Almost true but you can also access protected fields/method from class in same package.

Comment: Also from classes in same package.

Comment: Well, you're writing a JSP, so you clearly have access to -some- code.  You can still extend the class in question and provide an accessor method. 
    'public class MyImage extends Image' etc.

Comment: I do have access to code, but not the source class that would be necessary to extend the class.

Comment: You do not need the source code of a class to extend it.  You can extend anything you want as long as the class you are extending is not final.

Comment: @Aurand, thanks for the knowledge drop. I'll need to look into this more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is protected, and you are trying to access it from a `Servlet` subclass (JSPs are compiled into Servlets). You can not do that, by the java specification.

Make it public (if you have the source code), or extend the original class into a class that has a public method that provides the same data. Alternatively (not recommended), use reflection to change its accessibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make it public as I do not have access to the source code. What is reflection?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers you would have to extend Image, override canDraw and make the overridden method's visibility public.

What do you intend to do after checking canDraw()?  I imagine it is protected for a reason.  This is speculative but if all you are doing is checking canDraw() and then drawing if it returns true, you can actually just invoke draw() directly.  The JavaDoc states it internally checks canDraw():

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/ImageResource.html#draw(java.io.Writer)

Comment: I thought this was a good practice one to test, as it's value returned is only boolean. This is more for my learning than actual application.